# Copy an Excel Workbook Variable in VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ole-automation

Suppose you have 2 Excel.Workbook variables wbA and wbB. The first variable is a workbook you have assigned with something like Excel.Workbooks.Open.

Now my Question:
How can you assign wbA to wbB so that wbB is a copy of wbA and not just a reference to it?

I tried a simple `wbB = wbA` but that just seems to reference wbB to wbA.

Many thanks!

Comment: You mean to clone it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wbA` *points* to a workbook object in memory, it isn't an actual workbook. In the same way if you do

```
Set wbB = wbA
```

You are just creating another pointer to the **same** workbook that's in memory, albeit via another pointer.

If you actually want a *real* copy of the workbook then you have to do just that - copy the *actual* workbook and set `wbB` to *that* instance instead.

Comment: Hi! Yeah I thought so, damn. So I guess the only method would would be to do something like wbA.savecopyas and then pick that up with wbB right? Or do you know a better solution?

Comment: exactly that, doesn't matter how many variables you use you're effectively just creating a daisy-chain of pointers back to the same workbook in memory - so you need to physically copy the workbook and create a new pointer to _that_ one instead.

Comment: FYI, you can use `Set wb2 = Workbooks.Add("path to wb1 here")` to create a new workbook using the other one as a template.

Comment: Alright thank! @Rory: yeah I know. The problem is I do stuff with wbA first before assigning it to wbB. So I guess I will just save a copy of wbA to environ("temp") and pick it up with wbB.

Comment: It's just occurred to me you'd have an issue using the same workbook as a template as it would re-open it!